# Smooth Scrolling on Collapsing toolbar with tablayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to create a `Tablayout` with `ViewPager` that collapse at the top on scroll but the scrolling is not smooth and the tab swiping as well. This is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/htab_maincontent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">



<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/htab_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/htab_collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_gradient"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_header2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/girl"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_gradient"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/profile_gradient"
                android:orientation="vertical"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:text="@numerouno"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_settings_black_24dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@id/profile_image"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/followers_count_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:text="200K"
                            style="@style/follower_following_count"
                            android:textAlignment="center" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/followers_text"
                            style="@style/follower_following"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="Followers" />
                    </LinearLayout>


                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/girl" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/profile_image"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/following_count_text"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="200K"
                            style="@style/follower_following_count"
                            android:textAlignment="center" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/following_text"
                            style="@style/follower_following"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="Following" />


                    </LinearLayout>


                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/name_layout">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Bradt Daniels"
                        android:id="@+id/full_name"
                        style="@style/profileFullName"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location_on"
                        android:text="Hilltop, Mount View"
                        style="@style/profileFullName"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/yellow"/>

                </LinearLayout>



            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>





        <!--<View-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
            <!--android:alpha="0.3"-->
            <!--android:background="@android:color/black"-->
            <!--android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>-->

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/htab_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/htab_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white_70"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/htab_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Evertyhing works fine without the RelativeLayout. And I need that layout for other implementation.

I am trying to create something synonymous to twitter profile page

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you should consider ConstraintLayout in place of RelativeLayout.

Comment: I have there is no improvement

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with you, make it like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_stadium"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="350dp"
                android:src="@color/blackTransparent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_badge"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_year"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_stadium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I will check this out and get back to u